# NFC process Command Apdu method doesn't return command Apdu for Next response

Tags: android, nfc

Test Device: One Plus 5. OS: Android 10. Nokia. OS: Android 12. Vivo OS: Android 13 etc. When I take mobile application in range of the NFC reader it triggers first time then Deactivate and my Next Response Command is not initialize. In Samsung M33 5G. OS: Android 13 it is working fine. In no other devices it is working. I have given all the required permissions like NFC, nfc.hce and declare my service with xml in manifest file.

here is my Code for HostCardEmulation Service.

```
public class HostCardEmulatorService extends HostApduService {

private final String TAG = HostCardEmulatorService.class.getSimpleName();

private boolean firstInteraction = true;

private Emulation emulation;

@Override

public byte\[\] processCommandApdu(byte\[\] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {

  byte\[\] response = firstInteraction ? getFirstResponse(commandApdu) : getNextResponse(commandApdu);

    return response;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

private byte\[\] getFirstResponse(byte\[\] command) {

Log.d(TAG, "First \<-- " + ByteUtils.toHexString(command));

boolean needblekey = false;

if (command\[command.length - 2\] == 2)

needblekey = true;

emulation = getEmulation(needblekey);

firstInteraction = false;

return Iso7816.RESPONSE_SUCCESS;

private byte\[\] getNextResponse(byte\[\] command) {

return emulation.getResponse(command);

}

private Emulation getEmulation(boolean useblekey) throws InvalidParameterException {

String externalTagId = Utility.getCurrentUser(this).getTagno();

if (!Utility.isNull(externalTagId)) {

String passingkey = null;

if (useblekey)

passingkey = Utility.getCurrentUser(this).getEncryptionKey();

Application libraryApplication = new LibraryApplication(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(externalTagId)), passingkey);

Application\[\] applications = new Application\[\]{libraryApplication};

SecureElement seWrapper = new SecureElement(applications);

return new Emulation(seWrapper);

  } else {
   return null;
  }
}

@Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
  firstInteraction = true;
  }
}
```

I have tried all the other way but getNextResponse method not triggering. Only in Samsung it is working fine.